Compatibility issues between indentfirst and lettrine packages in latex
I am working on a book in latex and I want the first paragraph of each section indented in addition to dropcaps/lettrines. I have came across the indentfirst and lettrine packages. In the absence of lettrine package, the indentfirst works as intended. However, when both of them are used, the first paragraph of each section is no more indented as needed. I tried using \hsapce*{\parspace} and that seems not to work. I am not sure what the work around is. Any help is greatly appreciated.
Below is the M. W. E.
  \documentclass[10pt, twoside,]{book}                                               
                                                                                     
  %% Fonts & languages                                                               
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                                                        
                                                                                     
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                                                           
  \usepackage[english]{babel}                                                        
                                                                                     
                                                                                     
  \usepackage{indentfirst}                                                           
  \usepackage{lettrine}                                                              
                                                                                     
  \usepackage{lipsum}                                                                
                                                                                     
  \begin{document}                                                                   
  \section{First}%                                                                   
  \label{sec:First}                                                                  
  \lettrine{T}{his} is a minimal working example of the first paragraph.             
  \lipsum[1]                                                                         
                                                                                     
  This is the minimal working example of the second paragraph.                       
  \lipsum[2]                                                                                                                                                                                          
  \end{document} 

And the pdf file generated 

Welcome to TeX.se. It would be helpful to edit your question to include a small example document that people can play with.

Thank you. Apologies for my oversight. I have added a M. W. E. that captures my issue. Please let me know if more details are needed.

You can add space before the lettrine itself by using the ante key.
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\lettrine[ante=\hspace*{\parindent}]{T}{his is a section.}
\subsection{A subsection}
This is a subsection

\end{document}

There's no built-in way to set this as a default since the ante key is not part of the global options. However, if you're not using the key for other things, you can do the following.
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@lettrine}
{\renewcommand*{\L@ante}{}}{\renewcommand*{\L@ante}{\hspace*{\parindent}}}{}{\fail}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\lettrine{T}{his is a section.}
\subsection{A subsection}
This is a subsection

\end{document} 



Perfect, that works! Is there a way to making this a global setting though?

@bhache I've added a way to make it global.

Thank you Alan Munn for the quick response!
